# Cat State With Largest Number of Particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, schroedingers-cat

I am wondering what is the largest number of particles that went into creating a successful cat-state? This article gives examples of 6 spins and 4 photons. I am wondering if there have been cat-states with larger "objects" than this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_state

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_state#cite_note-fn3-3

Comment: Would a superconducting qubit count a as a large object? Each qubit is only one degree of freedom, but it's made of a huge number of particles.

Comment: @DanielSank I am aware of those. Since those are sometimes called "artificial atoms"  lets consider each one of those an atom :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the largest objects prepared in cat states would be superpositions of persistent current states in superconducting loops ([see here for example](http://www.rle.mit.edu/qubit/documents/Science_290_773.pdf)). The number of electrons in systems of this type is on the order of Avogadro's number.